# Совпадение строки с частью регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо узнать, совпадает ли моя строка с частью некоего регулярного выражения, возможно ли это? Например, есть регулярное выражение `/^\+7\([0-9]{0,3}\)[0-9]{0,3}-[0-9]{0,2}-[0-9]{0,2}$/`, мне необходимо чтобы допустим
`+7 = true; +7(915) = true; +7(915)A = false;` можно ли это как то сделать?

Comment: Если вы это хотите вписать в pattern то нет смысла.

Comment: да вот я не пойму, как вывернуть процесс, с какой стороны. Вхождение регулярки в строку - это понятно, а вот наоборот - голову сломал. Наверно саму идею надо по другому оформить? А как...

Comment: У вас есть конечное условие - конец строки $. Само проще - ставьте | (логическое или) с концом строки. Т.е. или ( или конец строки, и так далее.

Comment: т.е. задача тривиальна: чел вводит телефон, его введенные данные сравниваются с шаблоном, пока значение строки выглядит как телефон - все ок, как только введенный символ не соответствует условиям маски - стояночка

Comment: Т.е.  /^+(7(...)|$)|$/ и так далее.

Comment: хм, интересненько.. попробую

Comment: А не проще ли не давать вводить ничего кроме циферек, и просто проверять длину и форматировать значение?